# Handlebars dont wait for Ember Ajax

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

My Problem is that the handlebars is not wating for the ajax request to be finished.

My console is like this:

1. It starts with "starting" from the function in the controller.
2. Then
       the {{log workouts}} in the template which is undefined because the
       ajax is yet not ready.
3. And at the end the data from the request.

So this is a part of my code of my workouts controller

```
workouts: function() {
        console.log("starting");

        this.get('session').authorize('authorizer:custom', (headerName, headerValue) => {
            var obj = {};
            obj[headerName] = headerValue;

            Ember.$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: this.requestEndpoint,
                headers: obj,
            }).success(function(data) {
                console.log("ajax: "+JSON.stringify(data));
                return data;
            }).error(function(error) {
                return error;
            });
        }); 
  }.property()
```

And the Handlebars Template is like this:

```
{{log workouts}}
```

How do I solve this?
Maybe:
Is there a way to transform this code into a promise? Or is there a "wait for ember" option?

Comment: You don't load data in a computed property. A computed property is for computing something from something else _you already have_. Data loading generally belongs in route's `model` hook.

Answer (score 0):

You could do *promiseObject* or *promiseArray* when dealing with async calls and still wanting to use computed properties.

```
workouts: function() {
        var ajaxCall = ....

        return DS.PromiseObject.create({
            promise: ajaxCall.then(function() {
               // Do customStuff
            });
        });
}.property('blah')
```

And the Handlebars Template woud look like this:

```
{{workouts.content}}
```

However i only see the point of using this approach when you're property is dependent of another property *`.property('someId')`* And in this case you wouldn't be able to make query to server without the given ID. So when this ID comes around it triggers the workouts hook and gives you the neccessary queryParams..